# SQL Server : Change all DATE Records to a different DATE format

Tags: sql-server

I have a table called `SMS_OUTBOX` and it has a `varchar` called `DATE`, it already has over 30,000 records all of the `DATE` records are stored like this: `YYY-MM-DD`...

I would like to change all of them to `MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss AM/PM` but how do I do that?

How can I change all of the current records that are like `2013-03-18` to `03/18/2013` without doing it one by one.

Example use to be:

```
2013-09-17
```

I want it now to be:

```
9/17/2013 10:15:41 AM
```

or

```
9/17/2013 00:00:00
```

or just

```
9/17/2013
```

if no time is present.

Comment: I was hoping that you were going to say you wanted to know how to convert them to `date[time]`! why are you storing them as strings?

Comment: **Don't store dates as varchar!** Use a `date` or `datetime` type.

Comment: Couldn't agree with @JoelCoehoorn more. Store your data in the proper format and you won't have this problem. Also there are massive performance benefits for using the appropriate data type as well.

Comment: It sounds like some of your data does have a time component. Can you add an example of that includes how this time is current formated? one example from the morning and one from the afternoon/evening would be nice.

Comment: And your desired replacement string format is worse than the one you already have. It is not ISO and does not give correct sorting. Store as `datetime2` and do this formatting in the presentation layer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This expression should do what you asked:

```
convert(varchar(10), cast([Date] As Date), 101)
```

But **don't do that**. Storing dates in string columns is a *very bad thing to do*. You really need to convert this to a datetime column.

After you convert the column to a datetime, when you first go back and query the data it will look as if the column is in this format:

> yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff

Don't be fooled. The data is not actually stored that way. It's really stored in an unreadable binary format, and only shown that way in the query tool. You can then use the CONVERT() function to convert it to whatever format you want, or even better, just return the datetime data to the client app, and let the client app worry about how to format it.

Comment: Got it I will change the column to datetime Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly (you are just converting one column from VARCHAR to DATETIME) then this should work:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER COLUMN column_name DATETIME
```

[Alter Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using the built in CAST and CONVERT methods

First `CAST` your `varchar` to a `datetime` then use `CONVERT` to convert it back to a `varchar` in the format you want

```
update table
set [date]= CONVERT(varchar(20),cast([date] as datetime),101)
```

see also http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx for a complete list of date format options.